# How can I automatically derive Typeable instance for DataKinds derived types?

Tags: haskell, types, deriving, data-kinds

I had some types like this:

```
data Currency = USD | EUR
              deriving (Show, Typeable)

data Money :: Currency -> * where
  Money :: Int -> Money c
  deriving (Show, Typeable)
```

And I wanted to use `typeOf` with them in this function:

```
findRate :: Money a -> Rates -> Maybe Double
findRate a = M.lookup (typeOf a)
```

That didn't work, because the type `a` in findRate didn't have a `Typeable` instance. So I fixed it by doing this:

```
deriving instance Typeable USD
deriving instance Typeable EUR
findRate :: (Typeable a) => Money a -> Rates -> Maybe Double
```

However, that becomes a lot of boilerplate when the number of currencies increase. Is there a way to specify that all types of kind `Currency` should derive a `Typeable` instance?

EDIT: Also, a way to make it infer that in `Money a` the `a` is `Typeable` would be nice, so then I don't need to add `(Typeable a) =>` everywhere. That's minor though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `AutoDeriveTypeable` extension.

For the other part, the closest thing I could think of was to put `Typeable c =>` inside the GADT definition as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AutoDeriveTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

import Data.Typeable
import qualified Data.Map as M

type Rates = M.Map TypeRep Double

data Currency = USD | EUR
              deriving (Show, Typeable)

data Money :: Currency -> * where
  Money :: Typeable c => Int -> Money c

instance Show (Money c) where
    show (Money n) = "Money " ++ show n

findRate :: Money a -> Rates -> Maybe Double
findRate a@(Money _) = M.lookup (typeOf a)
```

Note though:

- By the nature of GADTs, this requires actually evaluating `a` to get the `Typeable` context out of it, which `typeOf` itself doesn't.
- This seems to ruin the ability to derive `Show` automatically for the GADT.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any docs on AutoDeriveTypeable, besides this (http://hauptwerk.blogspot.com/2012/11/coming-soon-in-ghc-head-poly-kinded.html)? It does fix the boilerplate issue (though for some reason I still need the Typeable derivation on `Money`).

As for putting the Typeable constraint on `Money`, I tried that myself earlier and now, and it doesn't let findRate infer that. Does it work for you?

Comment: @RamithJayatilleka The [official GHC docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html#auto-derive-typeable) are there, but that is just one paragraph. Oh, I *don't* need the `derive Typeable` on `Money`, this with GHC 7.8.3. Note how I changed the code of `findRate` slightly; the pattern match with `Money _` is what brings the `Typeable` instance into scope.

Comment: Oh I see. That makes more sense. Unfortunately, that end's up worse for me because I can't do `undefined :: Money a` like that. I'd have to do `Money (undefined :: a)` instead (or would that even work?), and I'd rather just put the Typeable constraint on. I think.

Comment: @RamithJayatilleka I think `Money undefined :: Money a` would work, but you're right it's not any better than putting on `Typeable` at that point.

Comment: Adding that `Typeable` context to the GADT will also add a dictionary to each `Money`, which has a performance cost.

Answer (score 1):

If you're tracking an older document that requires Typeable, you likely do not need it.  As of ghc 8.2, the explicit call for Typeable is deprecated and included "par for the course"; so no language pragma etc. is required.

Comment: The deriving is entirely automated. The passing around is not (fortunately).

Comment: @dfeuer may you tell me more about what you mean when you say "passing around"?

Comment: if you want an instance around for a polymorphic type, you'll still need a `Typeable` constraint, or need to store one in a GADT.

Comment: Good point. If your generic function depends on Typeable, `Typeable` must be included in the quantification clause.